# How to disable entire redux form after submitting and then re-enable it after clearing all fields

Tags: html, reactjs, redux-form

What is the redux-form way of disabling the entire form upon submitting of values??

and how to re-enable the entire form upon clearing of all the values in the form field of the form??

I know the html way is via `fieldset disable`  but I would like to know the redux-form way of doing these.

Comment: there is a `isSubmitting` key in `props` which would be true and false at time of submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the submit button , update the store via dispatching an action and setting the value in the Reducer.Then use the updated value in the component.

`constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        enableForm:true

    }
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
}`

```
`componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
     if(this.props.status !== nextProps.status)
      {    this.setState({ enableForm:true })
      }
}`
```

`handleOnSubmit()
{
    this.setState({enableForm:false})
}`

You can connect your store via connect from react-redux where you will get  the value from the store via props.
once you're value is set to false, you can perform a conditional rendering where the text Inputs are disabled.